# O que está acontecendo neste código o parâmetro event seria um this?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<script>

window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
});
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

O código em cima de 4 linhas é bem simples, mas me gerou uma dúvida em relação ao parâmetro event (poderia ser qualquer parâmetro). Quando você cria um parâmetro, mas não define o valor dele  ele é `underfine` correto ? neste caso quando eu adicionei o evento `contextmenu` no `window` e quando este evento ocorrer ele chamara uma função anônima cancelando o evento `contextmenu`. Mas neste caso não seria tipo `undefined.preventDefault()` esse parâmetro `event` tem qual valor? e está fazendo referência ao o que ? seria um `this` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso `event` é um objeto do tipo `MouseEvent`.

Ele não é `undefined` porque você não está declarando ele, você está recebendo ele. O valor do `event` é definido pelo código que irá invocar a sua função anônima.

Veja por exemplo:

```
function gerarEvento(callBack) {
    callBack({ tipo: 'click', momento: Date.now() })
}

gerarEvento(function(evento) {
    console.log(evento.tipo)
    console.log(evento.momento)
})
```

Qual é o valor de `evento` aqui? É um objeto com as propriedades `tipo` e `momento`, objeto esse definido pelo código que recebeu a função anônima, e a invocou passando esse valor como parâmetro. Isso é o que acontece no `addEventListener`, um código por trás recebe a sua função anônima, e a invoca passando um objeto, no caso, um `MouseEvent`.

Comment: Então, nesse caso o parâmetro event seria um objeto com varias informações contida nele ?

Comment: Sim, `event` é um objeto com diversas propriedades, incluindo o método `preventDefault` que você invoca. Você pode verificar todas as propriedades dele [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) (lembrando que ele também herda as propriedades de [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event)), ou então simplesmente fazer um `console.log` nele.

Comment: Então, muito obrigado @user140828 ajudou muito!